# How to get the full Node.js stack trace when using async/await?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have 12 `async/await` functions, and on the 12th one deep, an error happens. Right now, I have this code to catch all errors:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', function {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

The problem is, the stacktrace is not returned:

```
ReferenceError: sdfg is not defined
- get.js:29 Fruit.module.exports [as get]
  /project/models/fruit/get.js:29:2
- next_tick.js:129 process._tickDomainCallback
  internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7
```

On other projects, when I used callbacks with the structure of:

```
function doSomething(err, done) {
  if (err) { return done(err); }
  /* do something */
  return done(null, true);
}
```

Then I had a nice stack trace of where the error has occured and the steps that led there. Now with `async/await` I've tried catching errors at all kinds of levels with no result. I've also tried `longjohn` and `stackup` -- and I still get only the last function that threw the error.

Help -- how do I see the complete stack?! And what's the proper way to catch nested async/await errors?

**EDIT:** (a complete example)

```
const getA = async () => {
    await getB();
}

const getB = async () => {
    await getC();
    sdgf();
}

const getC = async () => {}

const start = async () => {
    await getA();
}

start().then().catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Answer (score 4):

This issue appears to be **resolved in Node 12**. With `v12.6.0`, the snippet in the original post yields the following stack trace:

```
ReferenceError: sdgf is not defined
    at getB (/path/to/test.js:7:3)
    at async getA (/path/to/test.js:2:3)
    at async start (/path/to/test.js:15:3)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to get the stack trace after the first await statement, in an async function, as of today.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11865

Answer (score 1):

`unhandledRejection` error handler might not be the right way to try to catch all these. I'd suggest wrapping your async/awaits in try/catch blocks:

```
async function doSomething() {
  try {
    await doSomethingElse()
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

This should give you a better stack trace.

Comment: This is what that gives:

 ReferenceError: sdfg is not defined
     at Fruit.module.exports [as get] (/models/fruit/get.js:29:2)
     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)

Comment: @JohnDerring that looks like a stack trace, saying that sdfg is not defined at line 29 of the fruit model. What am I missing?

Comment: The 11 other functions that came before getting to this function? In other words the complete stack trace...?

Comment: @JohnDerring is the `sdfg` error happening on `fruit/get.js` line 29, or is it happening somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, exactly. On `fruit/get.js:29` I put a `sdfg()` just to throw an error, so that's the correct place. The problem is it takes 11 other `async/await` functions to get to this place, and the error stack is just showing 2 places: the `fruit/get.js` and the `next_tick`). I'm confused about how to show the complete error stack...

Comment: @JohnDerring what stack trace do you get if you put `sdfg()` in one of the other 11 methods?

Comment: Thanks for helping. Here's an example: `http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmVERo` If you run that with `node --harmony example.js` you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @JohnDerring The only way I found is to manually add to the `stack` property at each step, [see this gist](https://gist.github.com/lll000111/3d6a53da4d53beb909189793c7631ba6). This is despite [this blog post](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-stack-traces) -- what this Google V8 guy describes does not work on *any* current JS runtime, I tried a few. It really seems that at this point you need a `try/catch` (as in the gist) for every step - which is extremely verbose.